# IEEEtran bibliography with bibtex formating issues

Tags: bibtex, formatting, ieeetran

I am trying to format the bibliography for the first time, I have installed the IEEEtran package and everything is working except I have a couple of issues, they can be seen in the screenshot. Firstly, I don't understand why the opening quotation mark of the title is so weird — it is different from the closing one, takes much more space and looks awful. Secondly, the IEEE format does not imply double dashes in the pages numbering and I haven't had any luck finding how to change the automatic reformatting. I'd really appreciate someone helping me with these problems. [image: screenshot]
Here's the main doc code:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, top=2cm, right=1.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\onehalfspacing
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\input{title}
\setcounter{page}{2}
%Abstract
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\large Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
\normalsize
\singlespacing
    Abstract here.
\end{abstract}
\onehalfspacing
\newpage
%Table of contents
\tableofcontents
\newpage
%Introduction
\section{Introduction}
    Introduction here. \cite{Xconference}
\newpage
%Main section
\section{Literature review}

\newpage

\section{Methods}

\newpage

\section{Results}

\newpage
%Conclusion
\section{Conclusion}
\newpage
%References
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

And here's the references.bib:

```
    \begin{document}
@conference{Xconference,
    author = "Sourobh Ghosh and Warren Seering",
    title = "Set-based Thinking in the Engineering Design Community and Beyond",
    booktitle = "Proceedings of the ASME 2014 International Design Engineering Technical Conferences \& Computers and Information in Engineering Conference",
    pages = "10-13",
    address = "Buffalo, NY",
    year = "2014",
    month = "17-20 August"
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why do you have `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in your `.bib` file? Apart from that I'm not able to reproduce the issues you've described. Try updating your packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a TeX distribution with an older version of `fontspec` which doesn't yet automatically run the option `Ligatures=TeX` when executing `\setmainfont`. If you change the instruction to

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
```

you'll get the typographically appropriate quotation marks and an "en-dash" instead of "--" to denote the range of pages.

While you're at it, you should also change the `month` field to

```
month = "17--20 August"
```

in order to get an en-dash in that field as well.

[image]